# Sharpening using Gaussian 3x3 filter works but the result is white pixels

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gaussian, convolution

The following program is not working. I am implementing Gaussian 3x3 filter to sharpen the image file  `FACE DETECTION.png`, but the result is just showing white color. I think the value of sum is more than 255 in convolution operation. I need a solution...

CODE:

```
int main()
{

  Mat src, dst;
  float sum;

  /// Load an image
  src = imread("FACE DETECTION.png", 0);

  if( !src.data )
  { return -1; }

  // define the kernel
  float Kernel[3][3] = {
                        {1.0, 2.0, 1.0},
                        {2.0, 4.0, 2.0},
                        {1.0, 2.0, 1.0}
                       };
     dst = src.clone();
    for(int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++)
        for(int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
            dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0.0;
    //convolution operation
    for(int y = 1; y < src.rows - 1; y++){
        for(int x = 1; x < src.cols - 1; x++){
            sum = 0.0;
            for(int k = -1; k <= 1;k++){
                for(int j = -1; j <=1; j++){
                    sum = sum + Kernel[j+1][k+1]*src.at<uchar>(y - j, x - k);
                    sum = sum>255? 255:sum;
                    sum = sum<0? 0:sum;
                }
            }
            dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = sum;
        }
    }


    namedWindow("final");
    imshow("final", dst);

    namedWindow("initial");
    imshow("initial", src);

  waitKey();


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your kernel. The sum of the kernel should be equal to one but yours is equal to 16.

```
kernel = 1/16* kernel;
```

will fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, this is a blurring kernel. If you want to sharpen, you need to use sharpening filters such as [ 0 -1 0; -1 4 -1; 0 -1 0].